# Controller not reloading the view after change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a list of elements, and I want to collapse to a single selected element on a click. I'm unable to make the code  on the controller refresh the list. What am I doing wrong? I thought that changing the $scope would make the view reload.

I made it to work by changing the $scope variable referenced on the view. So my guess is that the variables referenced on the view are treated differently than any other $scope attribute. Is that right?

```
AptListCtrl = ($scope) ->
   console.log apt_selected
   if $scope.apt_selected?
       $scope.apts = [$scope.apt_selected]
    else
        $scope.apts = apts
    $scope.aptClick = ($event, apt) ->
        if $scope.apt_selected?
            if $scope.apt_selected is apt
                $scope.apt_selected = null
            else
                $scope.apt_selected = apt
        else
            $scope.apt_selected = apt
        $('#selected_apt').html('Selected: ' + apt.title)
        $scope.$watch('apt_selected', (newv, oldv, scope)->
            console.log 'new'
            console.log newv
            console.log 'old'
            console.log oldv
        )
        $scope.$digest()




            <ul class="list-group" ng-controller = "AptListCtrl">
                    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat = "apt in apts"
                    ng-click="aptClick($event, apt)" ng-model = "apt_selected">
                    <a href="#">{{apt.marker_text}}</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this in an un-angular fashion. I made a plunk for you to show you how I would tackle this problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lT76dQvTKUxET5J6j3iV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

As @JSager pointed out, you could make better use of Angular. Assuming that '$scope.apts' is an array of items and $scope.apt_selected is the one clicked, you need very little in the controller. Just define the vars:

```
$scope.apts = {
    list: ['apt 1','apt 2','apt 3'],
    sel: null
}
```

NOTE: I changed your vars to an Object because ng-repeat creates a new child scope. In my HTML below, I use 'ng-click' to set the value of apts.sel. Because you're setting the value of a property of a var on the parent scope, it works, but if you tried to set the value of a controller var from inside an 'ng-repeat' it will not work.

What you want to do is more of a behavior. Behaviors are best handled in the HTML (and possibly with a directive if needed). You can show/hide things pretty easily with 'ng-show' and 'ng-hide' (both take a boolean value or expression that can evaluate to a boolean). Here is one way to achieve this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="apt in apts.list"
        ng-click="apts.sel = apt" 
        ng-show="apts.sel == null || apts.sel == apt">
        {{apt}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a fiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/gklandes/24FDj/1/